# Set tag's size attribute through css?

Tags: html, css, html-select

Normally you can do this:

```
<select size="3">
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah</option>
    <option>blah</option>
</select>
```

And it would render as a selectionbox where all three options are visible (without dropping down)
I'm looking for a way to set this size attribute from css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There ins't an option for setting the size, but if you do set the size some browsers will let you set the width/height properties to whatever you want via CSS.

Some = Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

Not much works in IE though (no surprise)

You could though, if you wanted, use CSS expressions in IE, to check if the size attribute is set, and if so, run JS to (re)set it to the size you want... e.g.

```
size = options.length;
```

Comment: Tested `size=2` in HTML & `height:20em` in CSS and it works in IE8, FF13, Chrome19, Opera12.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that this is possible.

CSS properties are very generic (applicable to any element) and are unable to alter the functionality of an element in any ways (only the looks).

The size attribute is changing the functionality of the element at least in the case of size = 1 / size != 1.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree, I have been able to set select width and height using CSS with something like this:

```
select { width: 5em; height: 5em; }
```

Works in IE(7) as well as I just tested it.

Comment: This is an old question but I was running into issue with Safari ignoring the **size=** attribute when using a size < 4. I was able to use the above suggestion in css `height: 3em;` to consistently set a multiple select to approximately 2 lines (FF8, IE9, Safari4, Chrome15). Seems to be a reasonable replacement for the **size=2** attribute

Comment: This answer isn't applicable to the question - OP was talking about the size attribute, not the physical size.  The size attribute turns the dropdown into a scrollable list of `n` elements, where `n` is the size.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select[attr=size] {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi marco, welcome to StackOverflow!  Please try to explain a little more about your answer rather than just posting code.  This will help people find and understand your answer.

Comment: This might indeed be an answer to the title of the question. The body actually asked for a slightly different problem. I edited the title to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following CSS selector to style select items with the size attribute:

```
select[size]{
/*your style here */
}
```

Comment: This might indeed be an answer to the title of the question. The body actually asked for a slightly different problem. I edited the title to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't add attributes set within html via CSS. You can add to the html using the pseudo selectors :before and :after, but that's about it, plus they still aren't compatible across all browsers. If you really need to do this, I think you'd have to resort to Javascript.

Comment: I agree. This strikes me as a job for jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

I do not believe this is possible no