# What is the css equivalent of the HTML attribute "size" for a select which is multiple?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select tag's size attribute through css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119961/select-tags-size-attribute-through-css)

There is a HTML select element which is multiple :

```
<select id="users_interdits" name="users_interdits" multiple="multiple" size="20" class="selectmultiple">
```

How can I write the css equivalent for this "size" attribute in the css "selectmultiple" ?

Comment: He didn't say it was your post. It means your question has already been asked before.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate. This is a select *multiple*, that question is a drop down select.

Comment: @MrLister — Since selects are rendered in completely different ways depending on if `multiple` is present or not — yes. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skeVF/1/) which, in Chrome/Mac at least, shows `height` having the same effect as `size` for one but not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get in the [CSS `height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) property (probably using [`em` units](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length)).

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in your stylesheet document.

```
select {
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: not px but em as Quentin said , px doesn't work , I tried it !

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin suggested, there is no "direct translation" of the size attribute in CSS. Even in scenarios where CSS is commonly used with select multiple, size is still specified. An example of that can be seen here:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-multiple/

If you are going to use height instead of size so that you can style with CSS, each size increment is equal to a 10em increase in height. However, this has only been tested to work in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8+.

Comment: the height works well !!