# use css to resize select tag in form to see all option tags

Tags: html, css, forms, printing

Is it possible to dynamicaly resize the visible options in select tag in forms? I have the example:

```
<select size="1">
<option value='1'>1
<option selected value='2'>2
<option value='3'>3
<option value='4'>4
</select>
```

I would like to have visible all options (to setup size dynamically with css) when design page for printing. And also to see selected option(s) in another design (color, bold ...). For resize I tried:

```
select{
        size:4;
}
```

but it doesn't work. I need a working solution at least for FF, IE, Safari ...

Do have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by `dynamicaly resize the visible options in select tag in forms`, they are resized automatically

Comment: possible same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119961/select-tags-size-attribute-through-css

Comment: If you need the options visible, then you might consider using `checkbox` or `radio` inputs instead. Or perhaps use JavaScript to replace the `select` with a `ul` or `ol` to show the relevant options.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: by dynamicaly I mean that I can change the visible size by using different css's

Comment: @slapthelownote: thx, it's actually very similar question, but doesn't give the satisfactory solution -> that javascript resize doesn't work in FF

Comment: @DavidThomas: That seems a good idea, but how do I do that with javascript. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use this way:

```
<select size="1" size="4">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option selected value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And don't forget to close the `</option>`